# How do I create a reusable node geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm primarily coming from Adobe After Effects and very commonly make animations with these infinitely repeating dashed lines that need to anchor to moving objects like in the video below:

https://youtu.be/qAUo089vdhc

I've created all the necessary models, however, I'm a bit lost as to the best way to create the animating lines. I *think* node geometries are my best bet. However, I'm curious, is there some sort of way to create a node geometry and save it for frequent reuse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are a lot of solutions possible.

Very simple one:

[image]

The instance is just a straight beveled curve.

Blender node trees have a 'group' feature. It allows graph code to be self contained and reused, much like functions and methods. The different trees you can select near the top of the panel all ac as node groups that can be called in an other tree.

Here we have the above example 'called' or used in its function form:

[image]

result:

[image]

simple animation:

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant!!

Comment: It is not …but thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Chris - I don't understand what I'm looking at here. In the second picture, I see a node named "NodeGroup". I don't see that name in the first picture. Assuming the group in the first picture was given that name, what then? Is it exported and saved somewhere in a library file, or is it accessed from whatever blend file it was created in? Is it then accessed using "File > Link" or "File > Append"? Even if it's being accessed from within the same file where it was created, how does one refer to it? Does it become an object listed in the Outliner?

Comment: @NewSites: you can make node groups out of selected nodes by e.g. menu "node -> make group". That's all i did for the nodes in the first image. You could "imagine" that it is a node group of the first image because of the same input and output names. So if you are a bit experienced in GN it should be clear.

Comment: @Chris - I'm a newbie, so sorry if I asked dumb questions. I was hoping from the title of the question to learn about how to make reusable nodes and how to reuse them. But I guess the question was actually about something more advanced and assumes I already know how to do that.

Comment: @NewSites: you don't have to apologize for being a newbie. But please ask "official" question - don't ask in comments because other people can't learn from your questions if you ask in comments. You may open as many questions as you like. You should also mention that you are a beginner in Blender so normally people will answer in more detail.